# Get mysql table data one by one

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrive mysql table data one by one.

```
data1
// wait 5 sec
data2
// wait 5 sec
```

Like this is there any way I can do That in php ?

Comment: You should need googling for this or if you have try something then share with us.

Comment: please give brief description what you want to do. your question is look like incomplete

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Add [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) to your loop to wait and pass seconds like `sleep(5)` how many seconds to wait.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use jQuery Ajax and create a function which call each 5 seconds:

```
<script>
     function getData()
     {
          $.ajax({
               method: "POST",
               url: "getData.php",
               data: { testParam: "1"}
          }).done(function( msg ) {
               $("#data").append(msg);
          });
     }
     setInterval(getData(), 5000);
</script>
```

and you need an div which show data

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

and a php file which we named `getData.php` which provide data

```
<?php
     echo '<div>Data</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getData()
     {
          $.ajax({
               method: "POST",
               url: "getData.php",
               data: { testParam: "1"}
          }).done(function( msg ) {
               $("#data").append(msg);
          });
     }

var myVar = setInterval(function(){ getData() }, 5000);
 </script>
```

this code added in getData.php

```
function myfunction(){ echo "Hello, Nice to meet You";}
echo myfunction();
```

Comment: The author asked about PHP and not JS.

Comment: Then php function here to call like echo myfunction();